# If all the sand in the Saharan Desert were to be removed, what would the remaining landscape look like?

Tags: geology

Would it look like any other region of the planet?

Comment: Not really sure about this question - if you remove the sand, you'd get down to bedrock. Most of the planet that isn't desert (or ocean or ice) is covered in vegetation or built environment. It's clearly not going to look like that. Are you just asking what kind of rocks are under the Sahara?

Comment: I'm with @naught101 Are you talking about "look" from a geological point of view or a geomorphological point of view?